# How to get sum from an object array by its ID - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sum

I want to get a sum of each object which will be classified by its id.

So, my model is:

```
struct MyObject {
    let id: String
    var amount: Double
}
```

And my data are:

```
var myObjectArray = [
     MyObject(id: "A", amount: 1.0),
     MyObject(id: "B", amount: 0.2),
     MyObject(id: "A", amount: 0.4),
     MyObject(id: "B", amount: 0.8),
     MyObject(id: "C", amount: 2.1)
]
```

The results should be something like this:

```
myObjectArrayResults = [
     MyObject(id: "A", amount: 1.4),
     MyObject(id: "B", amount: 1.0),
     MyObject(id: "C", amount: 2.1)
]
```

I tried something to do like this, but it didn't work.

```
for (index, object2) in newObjectArray.enumerated() {
     for object in myObjectArray {
        if object2.id == object.id {
             newObjectArray[index].amount = newObjectArray[index].amount + object.amount
        } else {
             newObjectArray.append(object)
        }
    }
}
```

What might be wrong?

Thank you in advance for your contribution.

Comment: `for (index, object2) in newObjectArray.enumerated()`, Isn't `for (index, object2) in newObjectArray.enumerated()` empty at start? So, it won't enter really the for loop? Also, does the order at the end matters? Ie, id A needs to be first because it was first in `myObjectArray`, etc.?

Comment: Manually, you can use `for object in myObjectArray { if let existingIndex = newObjectArray.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == object.id }) { newObjectArray[existingIndex].amount += object.amount } else { newObjectArray.append(object) } }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce(into:)` to calculate the sums using an interim dictionary object and then map the result back to `MyModel`

```
let result = myObjectArray
    .reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.id, default: 0] += $1.amount }
    .map(MyObject.init)
```

Comment: It seems this is working, but it's not in the same order.

Anyways, I'll upvote your answer. I would appreciate it if you can add also that part to sort it.

Comment: Only warning, and the author didn't precise it (I asked in comments), the order might change since Dictionary aren't ordered, the `map()` closure call order isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @ee.bt Well nothing was mentioned about any specific order in the question , so what is the expected sort order?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
for (index, object2) in newObjectArray.enumerated() {
     for object in myObjectArray {
        if object2.id == object.id {
             newObjectArray[index].amount = newObjectArray[index].amount + object.amount
        } else {
             newObjectArray.append(object)
        }
    }
}
```

But at start `newObjectArray` is empty, no? So it won't work. Then, the logic rest has be re-checked again.

You can do it like that with a for loop:

```
var newObjectArray = [MyObject]()

for object in myObjectArray {
    if let existingIndex = newObjectArray.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == object.id }) {
        newObjectArray[existingIndex].amount += object.amount
    } else {
        newObjectArray.append(object)
    }
}
```

The idea, is to iterate over all the objects in `myObjectArray`, then find if it already exists, in which case we sum, or else we just append.

With `reduced(into:_:)`, keeping the same kind of logic:

```
let reduced = myObjectArray.reduce(into: [MyObject]()) { partialResult, current in
    if let existingIndex = partialResult.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == current.id }) {
        partialResult[existingIndex].amount += current.amount
    } else {
        partialResult.append(current)
    }
}
```